# Validate Phone number textbox

Tags: c#, winforms

I want to know how I can validate a phone number in a textbox using this code:

```
System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex rphone = new System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex(@"^((\+){0,1}91(\s){0,1}(\-){0,1}(\s){0,1}){0,1}9[0-9](\s){0,1}(\-){0,1}(\s){0,1}[1-9]{1}[0-9]{7}$");
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try:

```
\+[0-9]{3}\s+[0-9]{3}\s+[0-9]{5}\s+[0-9]{3}
```

heres a little explaination of pattern above .

```
\+ -------------|> +sign
[0-9]{3} -------|> matches 0-9 max of 3digit
\s+ ------------|> a whitespace
```

matches with your sample:
+020 111 94546 333

if you want to validate if the number was completed lets say you got a button then textbox do something like:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Regex phoneNumpattern = new Regex(@"\+[0-9]{3}\s+[0-9]{3}\s+[0-9]{5}\s+[0-9]{3}");
    if (phoneNumpattern.IsMatch(textBox1.Text))
    {
        MessageBox.Show("OK");
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Invalid phone number");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
private void myTextBox_Leave(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Regex pattern = new Regex(@"^((\+){0,1}91(\s){0,1}(\-){0,1}(\s){0,1}){0,1}9[0-9](\s){0,1}(\-){0,1}(\s){0,1}[1-9]{1}[0-9]{7}$");
    if (pattern.IsMatch(myTextBox.Text))
    {
        MessageBox.Show("OK");
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Invalid phone number");
    }
}
```

Comment: please tell me the output of this string Regex pattern = new Regex(@"^((\+){0,1}91(\s){0,1}(\-){0,1}(\s){0,1}){0,1}9[0-9](\s){0,1}(\-){0,1}(\s){0,1}[1-9]{1}[0-9]{7}$");

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question. The input is a valid phone number in the textbox named myTextBox. The output from the `pattern.IsMatch()` is a boolean value indicating if the phone number passes the regEx.

Comment: yes i know that but i need to know how the number will input +020 111 94546 333

Comment: Yeah I am confused about what you're asking. A user would type the number into the textbox, when the textbox lost focus (ie the `Leave` event) is fired the validation would occur.

Comment: i want to know the rigth form should be written in the textbox

Comment: Well thats a different question entirely. You will need a `masked textbox` to do that.